Wordpress: Custom Dropdown field in Form for Ultimate Member
I have a registration form and a profile update form that I created a custom field with dropdown in.  When the user selects the correct name and saves the data, it inserts the row ID instead of the name.  IE:
Club 1
Club 2
Club 3
Club 4
If a user selects club 2, it inserts into meta "1" instead of "Club 2"
In the user update form I have it setup the way Ultimate members says in their documentation.
*DB Entry *enter image description here
The custom callback in functions.php per documentation
function ClubCallback() {
    global $wpdb; // WordPress database access abstraction layer

    // Table name assuming the table structure holds club names
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_Club';

    // Query to select club names from the database
    $query = "SELECT ClubNames FROM $table_name";

    // Retrieving data from the database
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    $club = array();

    // Constructing an array of club names
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $club[] = $row['Club'];
    }

    // Return the array of club names
    return array_unique($club);
}
add_shortcode('ClubCallback', 'clubCallback');

Form Image
This is what I used in their documentation
https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1884-custom-callback-dropdowns
    // Constructing an array of club names
    foreach ($results as $row) {
       //$club[] = $row['club'];
        $club[$row['club']][] = $row['club'];
    }

I tried the above but this does not work.
How can I get the result to show the club name instead of the value of the row?

I was able to figure out that in the array I had to contruct it so the key was first and the value was second.  Here is my updated code.
   foreach ($results as $row) {
       $club[$row['club']] = $row['club'];
    }


function ClubCallback() {
    global $wpdb; // WordPress database access abstraction layer

    // Table name assuming the table structure holds club names
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_Club';

    // Query to select club names from the database
    $query = "SELECT ClubNames FROM $table_name";

    // Retrieving data from the database
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    $club = array();

    // Constructing an array of club names
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $club[]['id'] = $row['meta_value'];
        $club[]['name'] = $row['meta_key'];
    }

    // Return the array of club names
    return array_unique($club);
}
add_shortcode('ClubCallback', 'clubCallback');


Please explain how this would solve the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers - This also applies to all your other answers by the way.. - [answer]

Not require to explain error in question code so give correction in code.
Please check it working or not

I've already explained to you, multiple times, that code-only answers are not good answers. How do you expect somebody that is fresh to understand this answer? You are not only writing an answer for OP and yourself, but also for future, maybe less experienced developers.

Furthermore, the produced array doesn't even resemble what OP actually wants - Did you test out this answer yourself then?
